# How to optimize the code of data addition to the datastore?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have the following code (for `Country` and `City` classes `key_name` is numeric id with addition of 'i' at the beginning):

```
def add_country(country, country_name):
  if country and country_name and country_name != '':
    return Country.get_or_insert('i'+str(country), country_name=country_name)
  else:
    return None  

def add_city(city, city_name, country):
  if country and city and city_name and city_name != '':
    return City.get_or_insert('i'+str(city), city_name=city_name, parent=country)
  else:
    return None
```

Is it correct code or can it be optimized somehow?

Comment: actually, this kind of question would be better on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @JMax, there are no GAE-related tags on codereview...

Comment: You can create some and at least tag it with `Python` which exists

Comment: @JMax, I can not create new tags there, since my reputation is still small :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to prefix your IDs with a character - simply convert them to a string and use them as-is. Otherwise, this is probably fine, though it's hard to know without seeing how you're using it and how you fetch the objects.